# Jquery scripts NOT working due to use of $.noConflict

Tags: jquery

I got 2 JS files called as " scripts1 " containing scripts of a slideshow and " the active link class " AND another one " script2 " containing scripts of " Mootools gallery " .
The 1st problem was a conflict between jquery and Mootools libraries that got solved using
" jQuery.noConflict() " in " script1 ".
But after that the scripts of " the active link class " stopped working which does work well if I remove the " jQuery.noConflict() " from " script1 " [ But then the Mootools gallery will not work].
I just guess there must be some logical problem about $ sign or something. If so, PLZ explain the logic behind.
By the way, I even went through the following solutions, BUT NO RESULT !!!

1. [Jquery And Mootools, .noConflict is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080095/jquery-and-mootools-noconflict-is-failing)
2. [Jquery-Mootools conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385048/jquery-mootools-conflict)
3. http://www.phil-taylor.com/2007/01/31/using-mootools-and-jquery-without-conflict/#.USjun6XI2ky

Anyway,I'd put the codes below and just hope you can tell me where im going  wrong.
The file " script1.js " contains the following codes :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ()      // the slideshow function
{
     jQuery('#SlidesUl').fadeSlideShow();
});

$(function ()                           // the active link codes
{
    var url = window.location.pathname,
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$");  
    $('#Menu div span #Menu1st a').each(function () 
    {
       if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, '')))
       {
        $(this).addClass('active1st');
       }
    });
});

jQuery.noConflict();

(function($)                           // the slideshow options and all
{
the codes
})(jQuery);
```

And The file " script2.js " contains these :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($)    // the Mootools gallery codes
{
    the codes
});
```

And here is how Ive put the libraries and files :

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src=" MooTools 1.4.4 " type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/script2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in `the active link class` executes after you call `jQuery.noConflict();` (it executes on document load) therefore yoou can't use `$` to reference jQuery any more but you do. To rectify this change `$` to `jQuery` or set `$` as the argument to the ready function which is in fact the jQuery object.

1.

```
$(function ()                           // the active link codes
{
    var url = window.location.pathname,
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$");  
    jQuery('#Menu div span #Menu1st a').each(function () 
    {
       if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, '')))
       {
        jQuery(this).addClass('active1st');
       }
    });
});
```

2.

```
$(function ($)                           // the active link codes
{
    var url = window.location.pathname,
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$");  
    $('#Menu div span #Menu1st a').each(function () 
    {
       if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, '')))
       {
        $(this).addClass('active1st');
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your jQuery doesn't work after calling [`$.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) is because [`$.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) will null out the `$` symbol that is used by default in jQuery.

I would recommend wrapping your code inside an anonymous function.

```
// Null the $ symbol used by jQuery.
$.noConflict();

// anonymous function.
(function($) {
    $(function() {
       alert('DOM ready!'); 
    });
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3v4CB/

**Edit**:

Try this:

```
// script1.js
(function($) {

    $(function ()  
    {
        $('#SlidesUl').fadeSlideShow(); // the slideshow function

        // the active link codes
        var url = window.location.pathname,
        urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$");  
        $('#Menu div span #Menu1st a').each(function () 
            {
                if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, '')))
            {
                $(this).addClass('active1st');
            }
        });

        // The codes
    });

})(jQuery);

// script2.js
(function($) {

    $(function ()  
    {
        // the Mootools gallery codes
    });

})(jQuery);
```